# When I run AudioBufferSourceNode.start() when I have multiple tracks, I sometimes get a delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, web-audio-api

I am making an application that reads and plays two audio files.
[CodeSnadBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-moon-ovfkt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
The above CodeSandBox has the following specifications.

- Press the "play" button to play the audio.
- The volume of each of the two audio tracks can be changed.

### Problem

When playing audio, there is sometimes a delay.
However, there is not always an audio delay, and there are times when two tracks can be played back at exactly the same time.

Although not implemented in the CodeSandBox above, the application I am currently working on implements a seek bar to indicate the current playback position.
By moving the seek bar to indicate the current playback position, the audio is reloaded and the resulting delay may be cured.
On the other hand, moving the seek bar may cause a delay even though the audio was playing at exactly the same timing.

Anyway, is there a way to play multiple audio tracks at the same time in a stable and consistent manner?

### Code

```js
let ctx,
  tr1,
  tr2,
  tr1gain = 0,
  tr2gain = 0,
  start = false;

const trackList = ["track1", "track2"];

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ctx = new AudioContext();
    tr1 = ctx.createBufferSource();
    tr2 = ctx.createBufferSource();
    tr1gain = ctx.createGain();
    tr2gain = ctx.createGain();
    trackList.forEach(async (item) => {
      const res = await fetch("/" + item + ".mp3");
      const arrayBuffer = await res.arrayBuffer();
      const audioBuffer = await ctx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
      item === "track1"
        ? (tr1.buffer = audioBuffer)
        : (tr2.buffer = audioBuffer);
    });
    tr1.connect(tr1gain);
    tr1gain.connect(ctx.destination);
    tr2.connect(tr2gain);
    tr2gain.connect(ctx.destination);
    return () => ctx.close();
  }, []);

  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const playAudio = () => {
    if (!start) {
      tr1.start();
      tr2.start();
      start = true;
    }
    ctx.resume();
    setPlaying(true);
  };
  const pauseAudio = () => {
    ctx.suspend();
    setPlaying(false);
  };

  const changeVolume = (e) => {
    const target = e.target.ariaLabel;
    target === "track1"
      ? (tr1gain.gain.value = e.target.value)
      : (tr2gain.gain.value = e.target.value);
  };
  const Inputs = trackList.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <span>{item}</span>
      <input
        type="range"
        onChange={changeVolume}
        step="any"
        max="1"
        aria-label={item}
      />
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={playing ? pauseAudio : playAudio}
        style={{ display: "block" }}
      >
        {playing ? "pause" : "play"}
      </button>
      {Inputs}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `start()` without a parameter it's the same as calling start with `currentTime` of the `AudioContext` as the first parameter. In your example that would look like this:

```
tr1.start(tr1.context.currentTime);
tr2.start(tr2.context.currentTime);
```

By definition the `currentTime` of an `AudioContext` increases over time. It's totally possible that this happens between the two calls. Therefore a first attempt to fix the problem could be to make sure both function calls use the same value.

```
const currentTime = tr1.context.currentTime;

tr1.start(currentTime);
tr2.start(currentTime);
```

Since `currentTime` usually increases by the time of a render quantum you could add an extra safety net by adding a little delay.

```
const currentTime = tr1.context.currentTime + 128 / tr1.context.sampleRate;

tr1.start(currentTime);
tr2.start(currentTime);
```

If this doesn't help you could also use an `OfflineAudioContext` to render your mix upfront into a single `AudioBuffer`.